# Getting error while deleting data from GAE datastore: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fetch'

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, flash

```
queries = [query for query in QueryHistory.query().order(-QueryHistory.date)]
if(len(queries) > constants.QUERY_LIMIT_SIZE):
    que = queries[constants.QUERY_LIMIT_SIZE:]
    list_of_keys = que.fetch(keys_only = True)
    ndb.delete_multi(list_of_keys)
```

I am getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fetch' error while deleting data from datastore. Please comment if anyone has a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your `que` is a list of queries, you need to call `.fetch()` on each member of the list, not on the list itself. Try this:

```
queries = [query for query in QueryHistory.query().order(-QueryHistory.date)]
if(len(queries) > constants.QUERY_LIMIT_SIZE):
    que = queries[constants.QUERY_LIMIT_SIZE:]
    for query in que:
        list_of_keys = query.fetch(keys_only = True)
        ndb.delete_multi(list_of_keys)
```

Comment: Do you still get the  `AttributeError`?

Comment: list_of_keys = QueryHistory.query().order(-QueryHistory.date).fetch(keys_only=True,offset=constants.QUERY_LIMIT_SIZE)
    if list_of_keys is not None:
        ndb.delete_multi(list_of_keys)

I have resolved the problem. I have used like this.

Comment: Of course. I focused on the error in your post, not on what else may go wrong :)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting :)